# Which query parser should I use to get results similar to db2 with solr

Tags: solr, lucene, db2, query-parser

I am trying to get results similar to db2 with solr query.

Since we want results similar to db2, we are appending a wild card at the end of the query phrase.

For example, if query is passed as `'the schoo*'`, then I want following results :

```
the school
the schools
the timpany shcool
```

I tried using edismax, but since we are using wild card at the end, its not giving apt results.

Comment: Yeah, cause edismax doesn’t support wildcards

Comment: ... uh, DB2 isn't going to select `'the timpany school'` for your stated wildcard.  No database I'm aware of will.

Answer (score 0):

You can use complex phrases parser

For example

```
{!complexphrase df= FieldName}"the schoo*"
```

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html

https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0//queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html

QueryParser which permits complex phrase query syntax eg "(john jon jonathan~) peters*".